# UV unwrap spiral texture

Tags: texturing, uv

I would like to have spiral shape texture on the cylinder. How to UV map the model and how to make a texture which wraps around the cylinder ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, unwrap your cylinder -- *Edit Mode*; Select all (<kbd>A</kbd>); Unwrap (<kbd>U</kbd>) -- with a cylindrical projection. Use a texture that joins the top and the bottom seamlessly.

[image]

Then select the bottom row in the UV window (<kbd>B</kbd> and make a rectangle) and shear it by grabbing to a side (<kbd>G</kbd>).

*Voilà*.

[image]